# How to put full text and image link into a custom rss with Concrete5?

Tags: rss, customization, concrete5

I am trying to pull content from Concrete5 to import it in Wordpress and later on on another different platform. I gathered that getting an rss xml with all the news could make the trick. I am a Concrete5 noob, so bear with me.

But by default I only get title, date and description, which is the excerpt.

The Concrete5 I am dealing with has news that are "news entry" and they have two attributes: Text Area "news_text" and Image/File "news_image".

Now... is there a way to put these two information inside the rss xml result so that I will be able to import the complete articles instead of just titles and descrpition?

I tried with an rss.php file inside blocks/page_list/tools using GetAttribute but nothing.

The concrete5 version I am dealing with is 5.5.2.1.

This is the code inside the concrete/clocks/page_list/tools/rss.php file

```
<?php 
defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");

//Permissions Check
$nh = Loader::helper('validation/numbers');
if($_GET['bID'] && $_GET['cID'] && $nh->integer($_GET['bID']) && $nh->integer($_GET['cID'])) {
$c = Page::getByID($_GET['cID']);
if (is_object($c) && !$c->isError()) { 

    $a = Area::get($c, $_GET['arHandle']);

    //edit survey mode
    $b = Block::getByID($_GET['bID'],$c, $a);

    $controller = new PageListBlockController($b);
    $rssUrl = $controller->getRssUrl($b);

    $bp = new Permissions($b);
    if( $bp->canRead() && $controller->rss) {

        $cArray = $controller->getPages();
        $nh = Loader::helper('navigation');

        header('Content-type: text/xml');
        echo "<" . "?" . "xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";

?>
        <rss version="2.0">
          <channel>
            <title><?php echo $controller->rssTitle?></title>
            <link><?php echo BASE_URL.$rssUrl?></link>
            <description><?php echo $controller->rssDescription?></description> 
<?php 
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($cArray); $i++ ) {
            $cobj = $cArray[$i]; 
            $title = $cobj->getCollectionName(); ?>
            <item>
              <title><?php echo htmlspecialchars($title);?></title>
              <link>
                <?php echo  BASE_URL.$nh->getLinkToCollection($cobj) ?>       
              </link>
              <?php 
              if(strlen(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($cobj->getCollectionDescription()))) != 0) {
                $desc = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($cobj->getCollectionDescription()))."...";
              } else {
                $desc = "";
              }
              ?>
              <excerpt><?php echo $desc;?></excerpt>
              <description><?php echo htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($cobj->getAttribute($news_text))); ?></description>
              <image><?php echo $cobj->getAttribute($news_image) ?></image>
              <?php  /* <pubDate><?php echo $cobj->getCollectionDatePublic()?></pubDate>
              Wed, 23 Feb 2005 16:12:56 GMT  */ ?>
              <pubDate><?php echo date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s T',strtotime($cobj->getCollectionDatePublic())) ?></pubDate>
            </item>
        <?php  } ?>
             </channel>
        </rss>

<?php   } else {    
        $v = View::getInstance();
        $v->renderError(t('Permission Denied'), t("You don't have permission to access this RSS feed"));
        exit;
    }
}

} else {
echo t("You don't have permission to access this RSS feed");
}
exit;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: perhaps you can post some code so we can see what you are doing?

Comment: Please provide more information like what you are including in the RSS feed and what code you already have. Also please include the concrete5 version!

Comment: Updated post with version and code